# Will Google Play Store accept self signed certificate apps?

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie developing an Android app. It implements a socket connection and has to bypass or allow all host for it to work with our self-signed certificate installed on a server.
I heard that google play store doesn't accept this kind of connection in the published app. Is it true? Or there is another way to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this.

Comment: @arshadshaikh yeah my problem is for now i allowing all of host or server to be trusted by the apps even if it is not secure. I just want make sure if Google Play will accept it, or there is another way to make it accepted by them if i upload my apps .

Comment: You have to handle ssl error for this. I think google does not allow above case for Nougat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and had to bypass or allow all host in order to work with our self-signed certificate installed on server

That was not a particularly good move, from the standpoint of security.

> I heard that google play store doesnt accept this kind of connection in the published app

The Play Store has implemented a ban on apps that bypass SSL validity checking and blindly accept all incoming SSL certificates.

> Or there is another way to do it ?

Android 7.0+ has [support for self-signed certificates](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html). I [backported that code](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity) to work on Android 4.2+. There are other libraries that offer self-signed certificate support, such as [this one](https://github.com/onehilltech/android-selfsigned). There have been [articles written on using self-signed certificates](http://nelenkov.blogspot.ie/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html).

Comment: Ah i see. Thank you so much. will try your solution first, then i will mark it as accepted if success :) @CommonsWare